# LNK4068 warning + LNK1112 error leading to build failure when setting environment variable PreferredToolArchitecture to 'x64'

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, linker-errors

```
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39           Lib:
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86\Lib.exe /OUT:"..\Lib\w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KerberosSupport.lib" /NOLOGO /LTCG w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSDialog.res
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSKeytabOptionsDialog.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSDSNConfiguration.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSKrb5API_Windows.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSUtilities.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSKinitSupport.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSAuthenticatedCredentials.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSCredentialFactory.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSCredentials.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSGSSAPIWrapper.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSLocalCredentials.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSSecurity.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39             w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSSecurityContext.obj
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39         2>LINK : warning LNK4068: /MACHINE not specified; defaulting to X64 [C:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\Drivers\DriverShared\KerberosSupport\Maintenance\10.1\Source\KerberosSupport_vs2015_NV.vcxproj]
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39    
05-Jul-2022 09:43:39         2>w2012r2\vs2015\release32mt\KSKeytabOptionsDialog.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' [C:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\Drivers\DriverShared\KerberosSupport\Maintenance\10.1\Source\KerberosSupport_vs2015_NV.vcxproj]
```

The error I'm concerned about is shown above; the gist of the issue is that the project file doesn't have `TargetMachine` explicitly set under `<Lib>` for the configuration in question.

Before we changed to set `PreferredToolArchitecture`, it was defaulting to the 32-bit build tools, and I guess that determines the default that gets used in the LNK4068 scenario

My question is, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/running-lib?view=msvc-170,

```
Usually, you don't need to specify /MACHINE. LIB infers the machine type from the .obj files. However, in some circumstances, LIB can't determine the machine type and issues an error message.
```

Is that documentation just wrong? It doesn't look like it looks at the obj files at all, just using the bitness of lib.exe, and it's using a default instead of erroring out.

The other question is can I somehow avoid this issue without having to update project files which were relying on this default? Could I somehow inject logic to default the value based on the project platform from the point of invoking msbuild?

Comment: If such an error occurs, specify /MACHINE.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/machine-specify-target-platform?view=msvc-170)(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1112?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I know how to fix it by modifying the project file, I was hoping there was a way to prevent the issue without doing that, since there's a lot of existing project files that I don't have control over that are built with this infrastructure